# What's the best practice to promote maven snapshot to release in 12-factor-app

Tags: java, maven, build, artifactory, 12factor

What's the best practice to promote maven snapshot to release in 12-factor-app.

I want to achieve build once and promote the same binary file, deploy the same binary file.

I am using maven and artifactory here.

https://content.pivotal.io/ebooks/beyond-the-12-factor-app

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. Why my question was marked as spam?